# How to use deep-equal (Angular 7)

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, compare

Auto import by VS Code:

```
import deepEqual = require('deep-equal');
```

Doesn't work:

> error TS1202: Import assignment cannot be used when targeting
>   ECMAScript modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"',
>   'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module
>   format instead.

Then I tried to do like this:

```
import * as deepEqual from 'deep-equal';
```

> error TS2497: Module '"path/@types/deep-equal/index"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.

And like this:

```
import {deepEqual} from 'deep-equal';
```

> error TS2305: Module
>   '"C:/Projects/ManagerServer/Src-LoyaltyCoin.ManagerServer.Core/ManagerWeb/ClientApp/node_modules/@types/deep-equal/index"'
>   has no exported member 'deepEqual'.

I haven't got ideas how can I import this. If there's no solution for this, please suggest me another library to compare objects for Angular 7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the script to your `angular.json` file :

```
scripts: [
  "node_modules/deep_import/name.of.minified.file.js"
]
```

And declare a variable in your component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
....
declare const deepEqual: any;
```

Or, you can find [typings](https://www.google.fr/search?q=deep%20equal%20typings&rlz=1C1GCEU_frFR819FR820&oq=deep%20equal%20typings&aqs=chrome..69i57.3031j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for it and install them, and import it like any other dependency :

```
import * as deepEqual from 'deep-equal';
```

**EDIT** Just a syntax issue. I suggest you [open the repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/deep-equal/index.d.ts) and see the syntax. The correct one is

```
import deepEqual from 'deep-equal';
```

as you can see in this [stackbltiz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b6xi8r?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I already installed the @types/deep-equal, but still have error

Comment: smth like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qjrh3q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @NastyaScherbakova Edited my answer, feel free to check it !

Comment: I see but it doesn't work for me for some reason
"error TS2304: Cannot find name 'deepEqual'."

Comment: As you can see it works on stackblitz, so you probably have another error. Try re-installing the dependencies, see if it resolves the issue !

Comment: error TS1192: Module '"path/node_modules/@types/deep-equal/index"' has no default export.

Comment: only if I change in library file on 'export default' it works, but it's not a solution :(

Comment: Then try `import * as deepEqual from 'deep-equal';` and use it with `deepEqual.deepEqual`

Comment: Can someone please clarify to me what this line of code does:
``` declare const deepEqual: any;```
We declare a const deepEqual, but how in world will that const connect to deep-equal library ?

Comment: has anyone tried with latest version of deep-equal ?

Comment: @user4676340 - Have you tried with latest version of deep-equal ?

Answer (score 2):

You may use `fast-deep-equal` package. It's included as peer dependency by Angular, but don't forget to add it to regular dependencies.
Also, it's the [fastest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-deep-equal#performance-benchmark) object comparer.

Usage

```js
import equal from 'fast-deep-equal';

equal(a,b); // returns true\false
```