# deep-equal 2.0.5 lib integration with Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, angular10, angular-dependency-injection

I'm trying to integrate latest version of deep-equal with angular application (v10). I added deep-equal version 2.0.5 as "dependency" in package.json (Assuming if this library is dependant on other libs, npm will auto download required dependencies). Also added @types/deep-equal to package.json file.

To use deep-equal, I added node_modules path in Scripts array in Angular.json:

```
 "scripts": ['./node_modules/deep-equal/index.js']
```

When I import deep-equal to my angular service to use the method in following ways:

```
import * as deQ from 'deep-equal';
import * as deep-equal from 'deep-equal';
import { deep-equal } from 'deep-equal';
```

But no luck.

My angular application starts giving error as require and global is not defined (from index.js file of deep-equal library).

Let me know if I'm missing anything or if I need to add other libs as dependency. I'm not explicitly adding require as dependency because Angular has its own Dependency-injection framework.

PS: The below SO link related to my question doesn't solve the problem, because it uses deep-equal ver 1.0.1 and I'm trying to use the latest version:
[How to use deep-equal (Angular 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53632149/how-to-use-deep-equal-angular-7)

Comment: DID YOU TRIED `declare var deep-equal:any;`

Comment: yes, already tried. No luck. :(

Comment: try - copy `./node_modules/deep-equal/index.js` file and paste it into asset and link it directly in your index page.

Comment: linked to index.html page and it gives error, require is not defined.

Comment: Hi Toxy, deep-equal is dependant on require. Is there a way those dependencies can be addressed ?

Comment: check in chrome dev tool if `deep-equal` is showing  - if yes then try check the spell and case and then try -> above import

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231365/discussion-between-sagar-agrawal-and-toxy).